# 'OpenFileDialog' doesn't take the value at the first time

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

When selecting a .dll file and press OK, the browsing dialog close and reopen. after it opens again and pressing OK, it take the values without any problem.

this is my code

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            OpenFileDialog dllDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dllDialog.Filter = "DLL Files|*.dll";
            dllDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            dllDialog.Title = "Please select .dll file.";
            if (dllDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                dllDialog.ShowDialog();
                tbRepTempLibrary.Text = dllDialog.FileName;

            } else { 
                MessageBox.Show("error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You call `ShowDialog()` twice - what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Are you concerned about that the first time only the FileName is displayed and the second time the FullFileName (including path) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are calling `ShowDialog()` twice. You should remove the second one,

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    OpenFileDialog dllDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    dllDialog.Filter = "DLL Files|*.dll";
    dllDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
    dllDialog.Title = "Please select .dll file.";
    if (dllDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        tbRepTempLibrary.Text = dllDialog.FileName;

    } else 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should not call `dllDialog.ShowDialog()` twice, use this instead:

```
if (dllDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  tbRepTempLibrary.Text = dllDialog.FileName;
}
```

and if the user click cancel because does not want to select a file you should not show `error`, it is the user's right to cancel without opening or selecting a file, you simply will not continue with the operation started ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `ShowDialog()` twice. You should just do this:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OpenFileDialog dllDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dllDialog.Filter = "DLL Files|*.dll";
        dllDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        dllDialog.Title = "Please select .dll file.";
        if (dllDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            tbRepTempLibrary.Text = dllDialog.FileName;

        } else { 
            MessageBox.Show("error");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (dllDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            dllDialog.ShowDialog(); // This shouldn't be here
```

You show the dialog twice.